# Possible to get all outputs to stdout in a script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos

I would like to log all error messages that the commands in a Bash script contains.

The problem is that if I have to add

```
E=$( ... 2>&1 ); echo $E >> $LOG
```

to all commands, then the script will become quite hard to read.

**Question**

Is it somehow possible to get a global variable, so all `STDERR` becomes `STDOUT`?

Comment: yes of course, http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/usr/rgs/mosaic/pl-exp-io.html ; e.g.: print STDERR "stderr 2\n";

Comment: Have you tried exec? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420278/append-text-to-stderr-redirects-in-bash - see also http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13082.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just start your script with this:

```
 exec 2>&1
```

Comment: Damn - should have posted by comment as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like:

```
#!/bin/sh

test -z "$DOLOGGING" && { DOLOGGING=no exec $0 "${@}" 2>&1 | tee log-file; exit; }
...
```

to duplicate all output/errors to log-file.  Although it seems I misread the question and it seems you just want to add `exec 2>&1 >/dev/null` to the top of your script to print all errors to stdout and discard all output.