# How to write to a named file descriptor in Bash?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I have created a named file descriptor `{out}`:

```
$ exec {out}>out
```

But when I try to write to the named file descriptor, a new file gets created with the name of the file descriptor:

```
$ echo >&{out}
$ find . -name {out}
./{out}
```

The Bash [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420278/append-text-to-stderr-redirects-in-bash) says:

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form {varname}.

If I do it with a digit instead it works fine:

```
$ exec 3>out
$ echo test >&3
$ cat out
test
```

How to do the same with a named file descriptor?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The string inside the braces is just the name of a variable the shell will set for you, whose value is the file descriptor the shell allocates. The braces are not part of the name. In order to use it, just expand the variable in the proper context.

```
$ exec {out}>out
$ echo foobar >&$out
$ cat out
foobar
```

In your example, the file `{out}` was created by

```
echo >&{out}
```

not the initial `exec` whose redirection created the file `out` stored the allocated file descriptor in the variable `out`.

Answer (score 3):

`echo test >&${out}`

If you do `exec {out}>out`, then `$out` gives you the fd number.